# Why do my Python executables not recognize filepaths when run as admin?

Tags: python, windows, administrator

I'm trying to automate a data transfer task from Excel to Access using Python. I've created a script that accomplishes the task, but I'm having issues with the executable created from it. (The task needs to be done by someone else, I'm just setting it up.)

I've created four different versions of the executable, all of which work as scripts:

1. Specify the Excel file using its absolute path, and enter the data into Access.
2. Specify the Excel file using `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'filename.xlsx')`, and enter the data into Access.
3. Same as script 1, but the data is saved as a separate Excel file.
4. Same as script 2, but the data is saved as a separate Excel file.

Both scripts 3 and 4 work correctly. Scripts 1 and 2 return errors relating to the Excel filepath as below. I suspect this has something to do with scripts 1 and 2 requiring admin rights, as the error messages I get relate to the original Excel file, which remains the same.

When I specify the Excel file using its absolute location, the executable gives this error:

```
[Errno2] No such file or directory: 'absolute location'
```

When I use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to get the location, I get this error:

```
('HY024', "[HY024] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] 'unknown' is not a
valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are
connected to the server on which the file resides. (-1023) (SQLDriverConnect);
[HY024] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] 'unknown' is not a valid path.
Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to
the server on which the file resides. (-1023)")
```

Comment: What is the value of that `file` variable when it happens, and what is the code that causes the error?

Comment: When a Python script is 'frozen' as an executable (i.e. when `hasattr(sys, 'frozen')`), use `sys.executable` instead of `__file__`.

Comment: Check the value of the path file as i said in the answer down plz

Comment: @eryksun Trying that now using:
if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    loc = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    loc = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file = os.path.join(loc, 'filename.xlsx')

Edit: This gave me the 'HY024' error again.

Comment: Additional information: The exe not run as administrator, when run, has the filename in its title bar starting with 'G:\'. The exe run as administrator has the filename start with '\\dcnas05'.

Comment: It looks like the ODBC Driver doesn't support UNC paths.  Map the UNC share as a DOS drive in the administrator logon. If it's a linked UAC logon, you can enable linked connections. To enable this, in regedit navigate to "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" and  create a DWORD value of 1 with the name "EnableLinkedConnections". Reboot, and drive G: should now be shared by the linked standard and administrator logons.

Comment: @eryksun Enabling linked connections solved the problem.